# How do I use sed to remove decimal numbers from a string?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, wildcard

I have the following string as an example:
ex. "Abandoned 16 1.10 2.62 3.50"

I would like to pipe this result to sed and remove all decimal numbers to leave me with the following:
ex. "Abandoned 16"

I was using the following command: sed 's/*.*//g'
which apparently doesn't work.

Can someone let me know how to use the wildcard character with sed to remove anything matching "*.*".

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't said what you want to do with the whitespace, but how about

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*//g' -e 's/ *$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

this would be easier with `awk`, at least for me

`echo "Abandoned 16 1.10 2.62 3.50" | awk '{print $1FS$2}'`

but is the list of numbers random afterwards?

if so, this works too

`echo "Abandoned 16 1.10 2.62 3.50" | sed -r 's/\s([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)//g'`

note that `\s` catches the white space, and that the numbers before and after the decimal are saved, so if you want to retain them and do something with them you can access them with `\1` and `\2` respectfully

Why catch the white sapce? well imagine if 16 came after 3.50 in your example you would then return

`Abandoned   [5spaces*] 16`
*I can only insert one space in this `<textarea>`

Comment: did you want to keep the spaces? you asked for "Abandoned 16" `awk '{print$1FS$2}'` should do this from your given string. note the `FS` which is field separator, in this case a space.

Answer (score 0):

Trowing in a awk solution that loops ovewr the input and skips entries with a period in them

```
{
     printf("%s ", $1)
     for(i=2;i<NF;i++) {
         if ($i !~ /\./) {
             printf( " %s ", $i)
         }
     }
}

$ echo Abandoned 16 1.10 2.62 3.50 | awk -f f.awk 
Abandoned  16
```